# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First - Include is being ignored when using LinqKit PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, include, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and am also using the PredicateBuilder so that I can build predicate expressions across multiple Specification classes (using the Specification pattern). I am able to properly build a predicate and apply it to a DbSet, and the data I get is what I expect. However, no matter what I try, it's always lazy loading. This is a simple example of how I'm building the predicate and applying it.

```
IQueryable<HairColor> hairColorQuery = Context.Set<HairColor>().AsExpandable();

Expression<Func<Parent, bool>> parentPredicate = PredicateBuilder.And(PredicateBuilder.True<Parent>(), p => p.NameLast.StartsWith("V")).Expand();

Expression<Func<HairColor, bool>> hairColorPredicate = PredicateBuilder.And(PredicateBuilder.True<HairColor>(), h => h.Parents.AsQueryable().Any(parentPredicate));

HairColor[] hairColors = hairColorQuery.Where(hairColorPredicate).Include(h => h.Parents).ToArray();
```

Like I said above, I'm getting the data back that I want, but it ignores the Include.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi jumping in late on this, but had the same issue with using an extension Include method when using LinqKits predicate builder.  The problem as referred to in the previous answer is that casting LinqKits ExpandableQuery to ObjectQuery (as required by the Include extension) results in null.

However found this link http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/ which is a Predicate builder which doesn't use AsExpandable to perform the search and hence the Include method can be used on it.  Although the solution above also worked for me this different predicate builder allowed me to keep my code cleaner/more consistent

Comment: Thanks! The original project is out in production now, but I'm beginning to understand more about how expression trees are built, and this implementation could be quite useful.

Comment: @DylanVester - you may want to consider swapping the answer box on this one.  Rearranging your particular query was a fix, but in the universal predicate builder from that link is definitely the more general fix.

Comment: Agreed, I have swapped the answers as this one was first and has more upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably [changing the query shape](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx). Try this workaround

```
HairColor[] hairColors = hairColorQuery.Where(hairColorPredicate)
                                       .Select(hc => new 
                                                     {
                                                         HairColor = hc,
                                                         Parents = hc.Parents // eager load
                                                     })
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(hc => hc.HairColor);
```

Comment: I rewrote the query as you instructed, and it looks like the thing that you changed was casting the resulting IQueryable from the Where method to a DbQuery of HairColor. Makes sense however, when I do that. I get a cast exception:

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'LinqKit.ExpandableQuery`1[DaycareDashboard.Data.Entities.HairColor]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[DaycareDashboard.Data.Entities.HairColor]'.

Comment: This makes sense, as the AsExpandable() is most likely changing the underlying type of the IQueryable. I did a quick google search to see if LinqKit.ExpandableQuery had issues with the Include, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help so far. Any more ideas?

Comment: If it's changing the type of the query, then how the heck are you calling `Include()` in your original? `DbSet` has that; I didn't think that LINQKit did. Am I wrong?

Comment: `Include()` is an extension method contained in System.Data.Entity, it extends `IQueryable<T>`. `LinqKit.ExpandableQuery<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>` so the extension method is available. I suspected that maybe the implementation of `LinqKit.ExpandableQuery<T>` doesn't care about the call to `Include()`, but I couldn't find anything on Google about it.

Comment: I see. `DbSet` [has its own Include.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=VS.103).aspx) But, as you point out, [there's a different Include on DbExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx). Confusing. OK, I have a rewrite in mind. I'll update my post.

Comment: Craig, I considered using anonymous projection to resolve this issue, and even implemented it, but I have to leave out the AsEnumerable because I still need the ability to apply sorting and paging after applying the predicate. I know what you're thinking, "that must be what is rewriting the query", but I'm not actually doing any sorting or paging in my code yet, what you saw in my example is exactly what my code is doing. So you're code may work for this simple example, it won't work in my actual implementation. Please know though, that I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do the projection *before* the paging. You can do the paging first, then project out the data you need. As long as you stay in `IQueryable<T>` space, it should still work.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! I moved it to after where my paging and sorting methods would be and it worked perfectly with one exception. While the first query ran selects data from both the HairColors and the Parents table like you would expect, additional queries were being executed to lazy load the child properties after that. I disabled lazy loading on the context, and it stopped making the additional calls, and the child collection was still being populated. I consider this question answered. But I am interested in why I'm seeing the above behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can guess. EF doesn't know that your query *just happens* to load all the Parents for a HairColor. So lazy loading tries to query explicitly. With lazy loading off, object fixup pairs the loaded Parents with the HairColors. EF doesn't know that this is the complete list, but since the entities are all in the same context, they're related in memory.

Comment: Last thing, and feel free to have my post this as a new question so you can get the credit. But is there a way to chain these anonymous projections so that I can do something similar to `Include()`, accept I'd have the ability to chain the projects like this `Include(hc => hc.Parents).Include(hc => hc.Children)` where both of these collections are navigation properties of hair color? I want to do this generically though. :)

Comment: Can you chain this? I don't think so. Not easily, anyway. Half of it *must* be done on one side of the `.AsEnumerable()`. Half of it *must* be done on the other side. That makes chaining hard!